# Websocket connection failing when using Nginx + Gunicorn + Flask

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, gunicorn, flask-socketio

I'm attempting to deploy a Flask app with Socket IO to a Linode server (Ubuntu 18.04). I'm using Gunicorn paired with Nginx as well as Supervisor to make sure the Flask app will automatically restart.

My problem is that whenever I try to load my Flask app and emit a socket event I get several errors such as:

```
1) Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
2) 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```

I've tried to use the Flask-SocketIO docs on Nginx and made my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flaskApp file like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name =IP; 

    location /static {
        alias /home/alex/blog/flaskblog/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/socket.io;
    }
}
```

This didn't seem to work since I continued to get errors like:

```
index.js:83 WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.domalertv5.dominuslabs.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=73fee616d7924a58b33041bfacf8caab' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

as well as

```
POST https://www.domalertv5.dominuslabs.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MoQWjbq&sid=73fee616d7924a58b33041bfacf8caab 400 (BAD REQUEST)
```

Edit: I added my Supervisor script in case that was causing problems:

```
[program:domalert]
directory=/home/alex/blog/flaskblog
command=/home/alex/blog/venv/bin/gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 app:app
user=alex
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/alex/flaskblog.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/alex/flaskblog.out.log
```

I'm confused as to what is going on, since the docs had this exact syntax as how to setup everything. I have tried to find other posts regarding this issue but failed to find one that provided an adequate solution.

Comment: Check your browser's console for errors. Also enable logging on your server to see the reason for those 400 errors. To enable logging add `engineio_logger=True` to your SocketIO object constructor.

Comment: Ok, I'll try adding the ```engineio_logger=True```. I pulled the errors listed in the post from the site console.